# How long is 11.10 supported? 

Tags: release-management

Im kinda noob here, but question until when is the support for ubuntu 11.10, I just update my PC to 12.04 but, when I install the video driver, nothing show on the desktop even cannot open terminal, just the screen properties so i want to down grade, and i need to know when will be the last support for this 11.10

Do that makes sense?

Answer (score 4):

**Support**

Normal Ubuntu releases are supported for 18 months. So **Ubuntu 11.10 will be supported until April 2013**.

Previous Ubuntu LTS (Long Term Support) releases are supported for 3 years on the desktop and 5 years on the server. Starting with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, LTS releases will be supported for 5 years on both the desktop and the server.

[SUPPORT RELEASES](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Answer (score 2):

Support for 11.10 ends in april 2013.

If your video driver works well than there may be issues with you user profile. The quick-and-dirty solution is to remove ~/.config and ~/.gconf directories:

```
mv ~/.config ~/.config.bak
mv ~/.gconf ~/.gconf.bak
```

To repair you video driver you can try to reinstall it with Ctrl-Alt-F1 and `sudo apt-get --reinstall nvidia-current`. If it will not help you can try to remove that driver and fallback to default video driver: `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current`.